# Replacing 3-way switch with new ones

Tags: wiring, switch

Trying to replace this old 3-way switch with a new [Leviton z-wave switches DZS15-1BZ](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GONGX98) + [VP0SR-10Z](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-Vizia-3-Way-or-More-Applications-Digital-Coordinating-Remote-Switch-White-Ivory-Light-Almond-011-VP0SR-10Z/100662434).
Both the old switches have the same type of wiring 1 BL, 1 WH and 1 RD.

But the new one expects BL, WH, RD and YL/RD (traveller) for primary switch and WH (neutral) + YL/RD (traveller) for the secondary switch as [per the manual (see 4b)](http://www.leviton.com/OA_HTML/ibcGetAttachment.jsp?cItemId=uG6NT9SjWaPsKV35Wr.W8A).

I am confused with this one, how can I check which wire belongs to the right slot in the new switch?

Upstairs:
[image: upstairs 1]
[image: upstairs 2]

Downstairs:
[image: downstairs 1]
[image: downstairs 2]

Comment: looks like here the white was used as a traveler.

Comment: Are there any other wires in the boxes?  If there are only 3 wires in each, then you are out of luck as there would be no neutral.

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of the box for the first light these switches control?  From what you're saying, both switches are on switch loops from the light box...

Comment: Updated with more pics.

Comment: Can you get another angle on the upstairs box? I still can't tell if the upstairs switch is on a loop from the light or not...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I have screwed the switch back in, let me get another pic in a couple of hours. What are you trying to find? If there is a loop b/w wiring from switch to the wall?

Comment: @zengr -- if the switch is connected to wires that aren't connected to any other bundle in the box, or if there are wires from the switch to the other bundles in the box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To move a 3+ way switch to a Zwave system, you will have to replace all the switches that control the light.  From the picture, it looks like what you have is the 3 way switch at the end of the switch run, meaning the red and white are the travelers and the black is the common here.  So that means the other switch (lets call it the main switch) will likely have the line /2 wire, the load /2 wire and the 3 way /3 wire that comes to the box in your picture.  If thats not the case, please notate that.

I did a similar setup last week with Jasco/GE switches.  I checked the installation sheet for this one and it is very similar.  So, the new z wave switch (at the main switch)will have 4 wires going into it.  The black wire from the line, the black wire from the load, a white wire (which will connect to all other white wires) and the red wire from the /3 connecting to the traveler connection.  Go ahead and put a wire nut on the black wire from the /3 wire, it wont be used any more.  Also connect up all of the grounds, and connect that to the switch.

At the other switch (the one where the picture is), connect the white wire to the common and the red to the traveler.  Put a wire nut on the black wire, its no longer being used.  Connect the ground wire to the switch.

With that, you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks! I finally got sometime and fixed it today. The key was merging all the white wires together in the main switch as you mentioned. It worked!